# Grouping vocabulary by common etymology

Tags: etymology, reference-request

Many English words have their roots in German/Germanic languages, and as such there is a certain amount of commonality between the two (similarly there exists commonality between romance languages like Spanish with English).

I recently came across this [vocabulary](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Spanish-Vocabulary-Etymological-David-Brodsky/dp/0292716680/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1491505869&sr=8-2&keywords=etymological%20spanish) book aimed at students learning Spanish, and was hoping someone might be able to point out a similar volume in German/English (written for either audience is fine, my German is rusty but passable). The book essentially groups vocabulary into common endings/roots etc, so differs both from standard vocab books and also standard etymological dictionaries.

Whilst there are lists such as [this one](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Englisch/%C3%84hnliche_W%C3%B6rter_Englisch%E2%80%93Deutsch) giving lists of cognates, I haven't yet been able to find a book such as the one I've cited, and any help would be appreciated.

(I hope this is on topic here, apologies if it is more suited to language learners, and feel free to migrate it there if deemed necessary).

Comment: Can one answer the question without buying the book?

Comment: @c.p., I can [edit] the post to describe the book better if necessary, however the table of contents is available on Amazon, along with the LookInside feature.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your way of learning a language and this method is not common even though with basic etymological understanding you can learn similar languages very faster if you cluster the words based on their etymological roots.

I dont know any book about this theme but you can try this databank: "Das Wortauskunftssystem zur deutschen Sprache in Geschichte und Gegenwart" and may be there is an extended search functionality to seach for etymological roots like "mhd", middle high german etc..

Comment: some basics: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_German_cognates_with_English